# Extract minterms from DNF

Tags: boolean-computation

I need to get the list of all minterms (as a list of boolean formulas) for a given DNF formula. For example for formula

```
x1 && x2 || x2 && x3 || x1 && x3
```

I would like to get

```
x1 && x2, x2 && x3, x1 && x3.
```

It seems to be something trivial, but I can't find a way to do it using Mathematica.

Comment: `List @@ (x1 && x2 || x2 && x3 || x1 && x3)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List @@ (x1 && x2 || x2 && x3 || x1 && x3)
```

> {x1 && x2, x2 && x3, x1 && x3}

```
(x1 && x2 || x2 && x3 || x1 && x3) /. Or -> List
```

> {x1 && x2, x2 && x3, x1 && x3}

```
Level[x1 && x2 || x2 && x3 || x1 && x3, 1]
```

> {x1 && x2, x2 && x3, x1 && x3}

Comment: Thank you for your response. I try all three options and that is what I have:

Comment: Both Level[x1 && x2 && x3,1] and List @@ (x1 && x2 && x3) return {x1, x2, x3} instead of {x1 && x2 && x3}, and (x1 && x2) /. Or -> List returns x1 && x2 as an expression (not as a list of length 1)